# activate next and privous button of owl-slider using jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel

hello i am new in laravel i am displaying product on silder it works fine but my next and privous button is not working. How can i work on next and previous button its customize code.. not bootstrap slider.
need help

controller:

```
$feature_product = DB::table('sub_categories')
        ->join('categories','sub_categories.category_id','=','categories.category_id')
        ->join('products','sub_categories.subcategory_id','=','products.subcategory_id')
        ->select('products.*','categories.category_name','sub_categories.subcategory_name')
        ->where('feature_product_status',1)
        ->get();
```

blade file:

```
<div class="ps-section ps-section--top-sales ps-owl-root pt-40 pb-80">
        <div class="ps-container">
          <div class="ps-section__header mb-50">
            <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
                    <h3 class="ps-section__title" data-mask="">-Features Products</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
                    <div class="ps-owl-actions"><a class="ps-prev" href="#"><i class="ps-icon-arrow-right"></i>Prev</a><a class="ps-next" href="#">Next<i class="ps-icon-arrow-left"></i></a></div>
                  </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ps-section__content">
            <div class="ps-owl--colection owl-slider" data-owl-auto="true" data-owl-loop="true" data-owl-speed="5000" data-owl-gap="30" data-owl-nav="true" data-owl-dots="false" data-owl-item="4" data-owl-item-xs="1" data-owl-item-sm="2" data-owl-item-md="3" data-owl-item-lg="4" data-owl-duration="1000" data-owl-mousedrag="on">
            @foreach($feature_product as $product_data)
              <div class="ps-shoes--carousel">
                <div class="ps-shoe">
                  <div class="ps-shoe__thumbnail">
                    <div class="ps-badge"><span>New</span></div><a class="ps-shoe__favorite" href="#"><i class="ps-icon-heart"></i></a><img src="{{env('IMAGE_URL')}}/images/{{$product_data->product_single_image}}" alt=""><a class="ps-shoe__overlay" href="{{ route('productDetail',strtolower($product_data->product_slug))}}"></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="ps-shoe__content">
                    <div class="ps-shoe__variants">
                      <div class="ps-shoe__variant normal">
                            <?php
                               $images=[]; 
                               $images = explode(",",$product_data->product_multiple_image);
                             ?>
                             @foreach($images as $image)
                              <img src="{{env('IMAGE_URL')}}/images/{{$image}}" alt="">
                             @endforeach
                       </div>
                      <select class="ps-rating ps-shoe__rating">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="1">2</option>
                        <option value="1">3</option>
                        <option value="1">4</option>
                        <option value="2">5</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ps-shoe__detail"><a class="ps-shoe__name" href="#">{{$product_data->product_name}}</a>
                      <p class="ps-shoe__categories"><a href="#">{{ $product_data->category_name}}</a>,<a href="#">{{ $product_data->subcategory_name}}</a>,<a href="#">{{ $product_data->product_name}}</a></p><span class="ps-shoe__price">{{$product_data->product_price}} Rs.</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              @endforeach
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Seems like there are no actions on the next/previous links. No JavaScript is executed, or no new navigation is taking place. You should enter the correct href info, pointing to your script, with a `page` parameter. In your Laravel code, use `paginate()` instead of `get()`. See documentation.